# Devise and unique email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Playing with Devise and noticed that if I register an account but do not confirm it, the email address is made unavailable regardless - surely the whole point of confirming an email address is to ensure that the person registering owns it. I want to stop "malicious" users registerting email addresses and effectively rendering them unavailable.

Surely Devise has considered this so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something Devise is going to resolve for you, since it's focussed on authentication, not user management.

A solution might be to write a cronjob with [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that runs a cleanup task. For example removing all unconfirmed email addresses after a certain period. This period should resemble your `:confirmable` settings for Devise in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: If it's purely focused on Authentication then it shouldn't offer registration at all then - this is such an obvious thing to offer though so it surprises me

Comment: Someone recently asked me "Why would you use your own authentication system instead of Devise?" so I guess I have an answer now.

Comment: Fair point. I have looked through the Devise docs once more, but was unable to find anything about this. As for your own authentication system, why not extend on Devise? Saving yourself some time.